# I tried to display out all the images in a folder into a single cv2 frame at a time.But it only shows out one image forever

Tags: python, opencv, imshow

```
images = []
folder=r'C:\Users\lenovo\anaconda3\mainproject\violations'
for filename in os.listdir(folder):
    img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(folder,filename))
    if img is not None:
        images.append(img)
cv2.namedWindow(winname)    
cv2.moveWindow(winname, 300,100)
for img in images:
    cv2.imshow(winname, img)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This code does work but displays out only one image.I need to display out all the images from violations folder at a time.

Comment: Is it perhaps showing just the last image? It looks like you show all images to the same window, each overwriting the previous image.

Comment: only a random image pops out in the frame

Answer (score 0):

The wait key is indented away from the if loop. correct that to as follow

```py
for img in images:
    cv2.imshow(winname, img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```